# How to provide custom soap fault message if endpoint is wrong or invalid in soap request in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am working in spring integration soap web service module for my project requirement. In my project if soap request  does not find endpoint then there is a need to send soap fault message like "Invalid endpoint", for example if end point to access my service is http://www.mycomp.com/mychannel in request but user sends in request http://www.mycomp.com/myproject, here I want to send response as  "invalid endpoint" soap fault.How can I achieve  this in spring integration.
please find below ws-conf.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycomp.mychannel" />
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<import resource="classpath:/WEB-INF/soap/config/g-config.xml" />
<!-- this is used for the endpoint mapping for soap request -->
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't valid or isn't full. Or I just don't understand you.

Actually `MessageDispatcherServlet` (Spring WS) just delegates request to the `SoapMessageDispatcher`, which ends up with `NoEndpointFoundException`, if there is no Endpoint with the provided `path` in Request.

And that Exception will be treated as SOAPFault with the faultMessage like `No endpoint can be found for request ...`.

So, be more specific, please. Looks like Spring WS already has all required features.

Comment: Hi Artem,Thank for reply.Let me be more specific:If request does not meet with endpoints in my application so it ends up with "NoEndpointFoundException" how do I  customize that faultMessage in spring integration. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since `NoEndpointFoundException` is a part of `SoapMessageDispatcher` and `ServletContext` at all, there is no access to the Spring Integration, so you can't customize that `faultMessage`. And even you can't override anything, because `NoEndpointFoundException` is some specific `WebServiceException` which is `final`, unfortunately. However you can try to overcome that with custom `javax.servlet.Filter` for that `MessageDispatcherServlet`...

Comment: Thanks Artem for your vital help.

Comment: Great to hear! So, if it is acceptable answer it would be good to mark it as resolved. Thanks